# sqPaymentForm doesn't work with IOS autofill

Tags: html, ios, autofill, square-connect

in any credit card form if I add id="credit-card-number" or "creditCardNumber or many other keywords in the input tag it will automatically take advantage of safari in IOS auto fill functionality including using the camera to scan the credit card number. 
it doesn't seem to work with sqPaymentForm. is there anything else I need to add in addition to the input id to make it work with sqPaymentForm or is square not allowing this feature to work with the form ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently supported in the Square Payment Form, unfortunately.

Comment: thank you for your response. I hope it gets support soon